# How to load trained RandomForestClassificationModel model?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have trained & tested a ML model (GBTClassificationModel or RandomForestClassificationModel). Then I would like to save the trained model for future use. so I did the following:

```
 model.save("...");
```

Take the GBTClassificationModel for example, after it is saved. the saved file is a directory which contains "data, metadata and treesMetadata". My question is how to use this saved model for future use? for example, I would like to do something like the following:

```
 model = spark.load("...");
 Dataset<Row> predict_data= model_model.transform(dataset_test1)
```

Any suggestion? Thank you.

UPDATE:

it turns out to be very straightforward:

```
 GBTClassificationModel model1 = GBTClassificationModel.load("...");
 Dataset<Row> predict_data= model1.transform(dataset_test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [RandomForestClassificationModel.load](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel$@load(path:String):org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel) method.

> **load(path: String): RandomForestClassificationModel** Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read.load(path)`.

In Scala, in your case, it'd be as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel
val model = RandomForestClassificationModel.load("/analytics_shared/qoe/km_model")
```

---

I highly recommend using Spark MLlib's [ML Pipeline](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html) feature:

> ML Pipelines provide a uniform set of high-level APIs built on top of DataFrames that help users create and tune practical machine learning pipelines.

With ML Pipeline it'd so much easier as you simply replace `RandomForestClassificationModel` with [PipelineModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$).

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
val model = PipelineModel.load("...")
```